# iText7 XFA - License not loading

Tags: c#, .net, itext7

I'm having issues loading the license files for iText 7 & the `XFAFlattener`. I've tried both loading the xml license from an embedded resource stream and directly from the file system with no luck. Calling `XfaLicenseKey.GetLicenseeInfo()` works and i see the correct information in the watch window, but no matter what combination of license files or `LicenseKey` or `XfaLicenseKey` i try, i always end up with the following message:

```
{
 "ExceptionMessage": "License file for product not loaded.",
 "ExceptionType": "iText.License.LicenseKeyException" 
}
```

> at iText.License.XfaLicenseKey.CheckLicense(LicenseKeyProduct
>   product)\r\n   at
>   iText.License.XfaLicenseKey.ScheduledCheck(LicenseKeyProduct
>   product)\r\n   at
>   iTextSharp.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener.InitFlattener(PdfReader
>   reader)\r\n   at
>   iTextSharp.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener.FlattenXDP(PdfReader reader,
>   DataPipeline dataPipeline)\r\n   at
>   iTextSharp.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener.Flatten(Stream
>   xfaInputStream, Stream pdfOutputStream)

```
var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using (var iTextLicense = 
 currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("myapp.itextkey-1.xml"))
using (var iTextXfaLicense =
 currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("myapp.itextkey-0.xml"))
{
   //itext 7 license
   LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile(iTextLicense);
   //itext.pdfxfa license
   XfaLicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile(iTextXfaLicense);
}
```

Comment: For issues with iText license keys, please contact iText support. We can't help you through Stack Overflow because we need you to send us a copy of your license file so we can verify it.

Comment: Ok, i've submitted a ticket in JIRA